# How to pass parameters with on-click event listener on html element?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, event-handling, addeventlistener

When a user clicks on a `<li>` element from my drop-down menu I want to pass the `year`, `month` and `dashUid` variables to the function that the on-click is calling. how do I do that?

I know how to pass parameters when using an event listener on an object but not sure how to do it with html elements. Maybe there is a Jquery function?

**Dropdown menu**:

```
function createCalendarDropdown(ChartObject) {
$("#navDropCalendar li").remove();

var dashUid = ChartObject.d.chartData[0].chartUid;
var dates = ChartObject.d.chartData[0].chartSeries[0].chartLabelX;
var january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december;
january = february = march = april = may = june = july = august = september = october = november = december = false;

for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    var splitDate = dates[i].replace(/\//g, "-").split("-");
    var month = splitDate[1];
    var year = splitDate[2];

    if (month == "01" && january == false) {
        $("#navDropCalendar").append('<li><a id="january" class="nd-class" href="javascript:userClicksMonth(month, year, dashUid);">January ' + year + '</a></li>')
        january = true;
        continue;
    }
    if (month == "02" && february == false) {
        $("#navDropCalendar").append('<li><a id="february" class="nd-class" href="javascript:userClicksMonth(month, year, dashUid);">February ' + year + '</a></li>')
        february = true;
        continue;
    }
[... all the way to december]
```

**The onclick function** (I want `month`, `year` and `dashUid` passed into this function):

```
function userClicksMonth(month, year, dashUid) {
$("#navDropCalendar .nd-class").click(function (e) {
  [somecode]
}
```

Comment: use $("#navDropCalendar").change(function(){ alert($( this ).val();) }) and you split this value to get month and year

Comment: But i want to pass a variable called dashUid too?

Comment: you can pass dashUid param like prop to dropdown or concate it in value   $("#navDropCalendar").append('<li><a id="january" class="nd-class" href="#">January ' + year + dashUid +'</a></li>')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom attribute and set your value in it.

```
$("#navDropCalendar").append('<li><a id="february" class="nd-class" href="javascript:userClicksMonth(month, year, dashUid);" data-month="'+ month +'" data-year="'+ year+'" data-dashuid="'+ dashUid+'">February ' + year + '</a></li>');
```

Which can be read in your function like

```
function userClicksMonth(month, year, dashUid) {
   $("#navDropCalendar .nd-class").click(function (e) {
     var _cMonth = $(this).attr("data-month");
     var _cYear = $(this).attr("data-year");
     var _cDashUid = $(this).attr("data-dashuid");
   })
}
```